# Function with cycle print 2 times before the first plot

Tags: r, function, dataset, cycle

My function prints 2 times before the first plot and this leads to misalignment between what is written and the graphs.

My function:

```
descriptive <- function(df1, df2){
        column_names <- colnames(df1)
        
        for (column in column_names) {

            par(mfrow=c(1,2))

            print("<= 8")
            print(summary(df1[[column]]))
            hist(df1[[column]], main="<= 8", col="blue",ylim= c(0,500))

            print("<= 18")
            print(summary(df2[[column]]))
            hist(df2[[column]], main="<= 18", col="blue", ylim = c(0, 500))
            
            mtext(column, side = 3, line = - 2, outer = TRUE)
        }
}
```

The result of first cycle (first variable) is:

[image]

The second one (second variable) is:
[image]

But since in the first cycle it prints two times the info before the plot everything is misaligned by one step. How can I avoid this behavior by the function? I'd like to have since the beginning the behavior you can see in the second cycle.

Comment: Is there dataset somewhere? Since you're iterating over columns, it's going to be rather difficult helping you if we don't know what data you used and how you called your function on it.

Comment: Unfortunately the dataset is private. The two datasets called for the function consist only of continuous variables from an initial dataset that has been filtered based on the value of a particular variable. For example, df1 has all records from the initial dataset with the value of the variable <=8 while df2 has all records from the initial dataset with the value of the variable between 8 and 18. I think the problem is inside the function I wrote.

Comment: I completely understand having constraints on using data, I've run into that many times myself. However, it is on you to make this somewhat reproducible, and it behooves you to make it easy for us to see and play. Find a public dataset that has just enough of what you need; for this example, you should be able to adapt even `mtcars` (perhaps using `< 6` and `> 6` for your comparisons).